Query about extender embeddings
This seems as though it should be a result which is possible to prove but I was just wondering if I have it right and also if there is a source for it.
Suppose that $j:V_{\alpha} \rightarrow V_{\beta}$ is an elementary embedding with $j(\kappa)>\alpha$ and $\beta$ a fixed point of the beth function. Is this extendible to a $j:V \rightarrow M$ with $V_{\beta} \subseteq M$?
EDIT: A friend has made the comment that it might be necessary to assume that $j$ is cofinal and $\beta$ has cofinality $>\omega$.
